# passing value from view to controller without using <form> codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

can someone give me some tips on how can i pass a value from a view to a function in a controller without using a form? i just use only  thanks here is my code.

view:

```
     <ul>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/passby">Add subject</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
```

controller:

```
  public function passby($page){

        $uri = 'admin/'.$page;
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('admin/navigation');
        $this->load->view('admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view($uri);
        $this->load->view('footer');
  }
```

i want to put a value on the anchor tag and pass it to the controller as a parameter page so that my page will load the view without using may functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass, (for example a string) on the URI segment. Example:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/passby/1">Add subject</a></li>
                                              //  ^ 1 just for example
```

Or concatenate a variable:

```
<?php $id = 123; ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'main/passby/' . $id; ?>">Add subject</a></li>
```

Then you can use it on the function.

```
public function passby($page)
{
    // $page = 1;
}
```

Comment: how can i make 1 as a variable? because i want to make it as a dynamic page ...is it posible like this for example            

@Ghost
      <li><a href="<?php $page='add_subj'; echo base_url(); ?>main/passby/$page">Add subject</a></li>

Comment: @RenzSegerBu-ong yes that's just an example you can put a string and use that on the passby method, use the `$page`

Comment: @RenzSegerBu-ong yes you can concatenate a variable on that so that you can use it up on passby